# Definition of homogeneous ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, terminology, definition

In my lecture notes, it gives this following definition of a homogeneous ODE:

> A differential equation is called homogeneous if it can be written in
>   the form $x′=f(\frac{x}{t})$

Then in one of the questions, it says that $\frac{dy}{dt} + t^2y = y$ is a homogenous ODE.

Rearranging, we get $\frac{dy}{dt} = y(1-t^2) = y(1-t)(1+t)$

How can this be written in the form $\frac{dy}{dt}=f(\frac{y}{t})$?

Comment: Oh yeah, made an error in the question. Fixed it now.

Comment: "Homogenous" means different things in the two cases.

Comment: This equation is "homogenous" because all the terms contain y or it's derivatives.

Comment: http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there are [two different uses of the word *homogeneous*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homogeneous_differential_equation) in the context of differential equations.

Most generally, let use suppose we have an ordinary differential equation of first order of the form 
$$ x' = F(x,t). $$
Sometimes there is a natural symmetry to the equations such that there exists $p$, $q$ real numbers such that:

> whenever $x(t)$ is a solution, so is the function $y(t) = \lambda^p x(\lambda^q t)$ for any $\lambda$.

(Note that without loss of generality we can assume that at least one of $p,q$ is $1$.)

Necessarily for this to be true, by plugging into the equation, we have that

$$ y'(t) = \lambda^{p+q} x'(\lambda^q t) $$

which implies

$$ \lambda^{p+q} F( x,\lambda^q t) = F(\lambda^p x, t) $$

which gives a *functional relation* for $F$ and restricts the form $F$ can take.

---

The two distinct meanings of the word homogeneous refers to

1. The case where $p = 1$ and $q = 0$. That is to say: whenever $x(t)$ is a solution, so is $\lambda x(t)$. This seems to be the sense in which the "question" is using.
2. The case where $p = 1$ and $q = -1$. Here we have $F(\lambda x,t) = F(x,\lambda^{-1}t)$. This implies that there exists some function $f$ such that $F(x,t) = f(x/t)$.

Comment: So the lecture note was about $(1,-1)$-homogeneity and the question about $(1,0)$-homogeneity, which is obviously not the same for those guys who know their $(p,q)$-homogeneity well? :-)

Comment: I wish they'd explain this to us, some of our lectures notes are really quite sloppy in areas, mostly with the more applied modules. Thanks anyway :)

Comment: @CameronMartin: you are not the only one. Unfortunately, this is one of those things that, over the past 10 or 20 years have become second nature to your lecturer. Sometimes it is really hard to put ourselves in the shoes of a student! I think one should definitely ask these kinds of questions in class. I for one would be glad if you asked about this when I am teaching: at the very least the next time I teach the class I will remember that "here be a pitfall, make it clear."

Comment: @mvw: well... I don't know whether the terminology $(p,q)$-homogeneity is used anywhere outside of my head. This notion is useful because it "reduces" the space of solutions a bit. Generally the set of solutions to a first order ODE is one-dimensional, it being parametrised by the initial data. These kinds of relations reduces the solution family to be effectively 0 dimensional, which is useful if you want to talk about asymptotic behaviour and things like that. Related is also the scaling behaviour in PDEs which can help in constructing explicit solutions.

Answer (score 1):

If $y$ is a solution of the ODE $L(y) = 0$ and we try for $c y$ with some constant $c$, we get

$$
L (c y) = (c y)' + t^2(c y) - (cy) = c (y' + t^2 y - y) = c L(y) = c \cdot 0 = 0
$$

so the multiple is a solution too. It is homogenous, which correspponds to the more often seen definition that there is no term $f(t)$ (the inhomogenity, which is usually written on the right hand side).

I see no way to write
$$ 
y' = (1 -t^2) y = (t - t^3) \frac{y}{t}
$$
just as $y' = F(y/t)$ with $F$ having no $y$ and $t$ used.

Answer (score 0):

A linear differential equation is called homogenous if any linear combination of a given set of solutions is also a solution.

$y'(t)=y(t)(t^{2}-1)$ is an example of such an equation.