# what will be the basic definition of homogenous equation for a novice?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

what will be the basic definition of homogenous equation for a novice? have already seen [Definition of homogeneous ODE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/805397/definition-of-homogeneous-ode) and dint get any wiser. help me like a kid who just encountered this word "homogeneous" and is weak at maths. 
thank you already

Comment: Beware: there are two different meanings of "homogeneous". The most widespread meaning is "a differential equation with right hand side 0".

Comment: One reason to take linear algebra before taking differential equations.

Comment: yeah i know i got to clear up my basics. but education system in my country doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic definition of homogeneous is that it makes no difference if you multiply every variable by some (nonzero) number $k$.  If $f(x,y)$ is a function of two variables, then we'd call it "homogeneous" if $f(kx,ky) = k^df(x,y).$  In differential equations, the $d$ is usually 0.  The function $f(x,y) = x^2+y^2$ is homogeneous of degree 2 because $f(kx,ky) = k^2f(x,y).$

This definition manifests itself in two ways in DE.  In 1st order equations, a DE is "homogeneous" if we can write $y^{\prime} = f(x,y) = g(y/x)$.  See that in this case, $f(kx,xy) = g(ky/kx) = g(y/x) = f(x,y)$.

In 2nd order equations, we call a linear DE "homogeneous" if there is no lone function of $t$.  Such as $y^{\prime\prime}+4y^{\prime} + 3y = 0$.  See that if you replace $y$ by $ky$ in this equation, the $k$ factors out and you can divide it away, leaving you with the equation you started with.

Comment: if i replace y with ky and divide k away, i will still have k^n-1 left

Comment: $k^n-1$ $y^n$ + 4y' + 3y = 0.  @B.Goddard

Comment: sorry $k^(n-1)$

Comment: i think you get my meaning. cant correct it

Comment: @ShoryaSharma I typed $y^{\prime\prime}$, not $y^n$.

Comment: sorry sir. should have read correctly